# Text-align: center doesn't work when hiding then unhiding a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button at the bottom of my page that I hide and unhide by setting its style to display:none and display:block respectively. I do this with many objects multiple times throughout my code, so I use the following function:

```
function objectHide(object, hide) {
  if (hide == 'hide') {
  document.getElementById(object).style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (hide == 'unhide') {
  document.getElementById(object).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Once the button has been hidden and unhidden once it is no longer aligned to the center of the page and defaults to the standard left side.

Text-align center is attached to the body, but I have also tried attaching it to the button's parent div, both in CSS and in Javascript after it is unhidden. None of these have worked and it continues to change back to the standard left side.

Comment: Please share a [mre]

Comment: If the button's initial `display` is not `block` then unhiding it may well change its alignment. Does setting `style.display = ""` exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: initial value of display, if not overridden, for button is inline, so unhiding means same exact value, which is not block as it seems

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `.display` for this then you'll have to set the style property again when unhiding. Otherwise, you can toggling the `.visibility` property of your UI element. This should accomplish what you're trying to achieve here.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put the hide function in the button's parent element. Something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="btn-container>
<button>Click here</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#btn-container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

For the JavaScript:

```
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn-container")
if (btn.style.display === "flex") {
btn.style.display = "none"
}else{
btn.style.display = "flex"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN [See Also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#see_also) section for `initial`:

> - Use the [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) keyword to reset a property to the value established by the user-agent stylesheet (or by user styles, if any exist)

Using `revert` means you don't have to determine what an element's `display` attribute should be to re-display the item.

```js
"use strict";
hide.onclick=()=>btn.style.display="none";
show.onclick=()=>btn.style.display="revert";
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Centered Button</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>
<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
```

Note the code snippet techniques of using the variables created for element ids is for brevity and not recommended in production (they may be shadowed by global variables or functions of the same name).